# Bypass Visio Print Confirmation using VBScript

Tags: pdf, printing, vbscript, visio

I need to convert hundreds of visio drawings to PDF. I can right click these and press print but I get a confirmation print box for every document I need to print. I thought about using the following code to print all documents in the folder to my default printer (PDF) however this also asks for confirmation. Does anyone know how to alter the code so I dont have to manually confirm each time?

```
set shApp = CreateObject("shell.application")
currentPath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".") 
set shFolder = shApp.NameSpace( currentPath )
set files = shFolder.Items()
for each files in files

if files.name <> Wscript.ScriptName then
    'msgbox("printing "&files.name)
     files.InvokeVerbEx ("Print") 
end if
next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Visio directly, and do "save as pdf" programmatically:

```
set shApp = CreateObject("shell.application")

Set visioApp = CreateObject("Visio.InvisibleApp") ' start invisible Visio app

currentPath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".") 
set shFolder = shApp.NameSpace( currentPath )
set files = shFolder.Items()
for each files in files

if files.name <> Wscript.ScriptName then 
    ' msgbox("printing "&files.name)
    ' files.InvokeVerbEx ("Print") 

    set doc = visioApp.Documents.OpenEx(files.path, 1+2+128+256) ' name, readonly + copy + macro disabled + no workspace
    doc.ExportAsFixedFormat 1, files.path & ".pdf", 1, 0 ' pdf, filename, printer quality, print all
    doc.Close

end if
next

visioApp.Quit
```

See more about ExportAsFixedFormat in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff766893.aspx)

Comment: thanks for that but unfortunately I couldnt use that method as my company are using Visio 2002 and it didnt support it. From what you gave me though I managed to print from the application to my default PDF printer which works great and doesnt ask me to confirm. Also love the invisible app so it doesnt appear: set doc = visioapp.documents.open(files.path) doc.Print. Thank you

Comment: Also do you know of any way to alter the filename when it prints to PDF as currently everytime I print to PDF from Visio the file appears in the directory as Visio-filename.pdf I do have a seperate script that loops all files removing this but it would be nice if it just created then with just filename.pdf from the beginning?

Comment: I suppose this is default file name. (i.e. the printed file is named after the source file). Maybe it can be configured somehow in the "pdf printer" settings, not sure.. Other than that no idea except what you have already voiced - just post-process files with the script :)

Answer (score 0):

For those using Visio 2007 or later then Nikolay's answer is the best solution. However if like me your using anything below 2007 then the following will loop files and print each one without asking for confirmation:

```
set shApp = CreateObject("shell.application")
Set visioApp = CreateObject("Visio.InvisibleApp") ' start invisible Visio app

currentPath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".") 
set shFolder = shApp.NameSpace( currentPath )
set files = shFolder.Items()
for each files in files

  if files.name <> Wscript.ScriptName then 

set doc = visioapp.documents.open(files.path)
doc.Printer = "\\bprintpdf1\PDF4Printing"
doc.Print
      doc.Close

   end if
next

visioApp.Quit
```